# How to pass a dictionary created upstream to a task downstream in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to create a dictionary by reading BQ data and then want to iterate over the items in another task -

The code I've written so far, but it's throwing error as

> for x,y in mydict.items(): NameError: name 'mydict' is not defined

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the error? When I was not iterating over the mydict.items(), I ran the dag and checked the XCom values correctly populated as

> Key                Values -  return_value
> {"1":"name_1","2":"name_2","3":"name_3"}

Which means mydict is being stored in XCom variable then why it doesn't get recognized in downstream task?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryHook
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': '',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    'retries': 0,
}


def get_bq_data():
    mydict = {}
    config={
        "job_type":"Query",
        "query":{
            "query":"select number,name from my_project.my_dataset.my_table",
            "useLegacySql":False,
            "allow_large_results":True,
            "location":"location_name"
        }}
    hook = BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    target_data=hook.insert_job(configuration=config, project_id=None, nowait=False)
    for row in target_data.result():
        mydict[row.number] = row.name
    return mydict
    

with DAG('test_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, catchup=False) as dag:
    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='bash_task',
        bash_command="echo 'This is outside for loop'"
    )
    
    get_mydict = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_mydict',
        python_callable=get_bq_data,
        provide_context=True
    )
     
    bash_task >> get_mydict
    for x,y in mydict.items():
    
        run_test_2 = BashOperator(
        task_id=f'task2_{y}',
        bash_command=f"echo '{x}'"
        )
        
        [get_mydict] >> run_test_2
```

I've updated my code to pull the mydict value, but I'm still getting below error. What am I doing wrong?

> ```
> print(f'printing mydict in pull_function ---> {mydict}') NameError: name 'mydict' is not defined
> ```

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryHook
from datetime import datetime
import json

default_args = {
    'owner': '',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    'retries': 0,
}


def get_bq_data(**context):
    mydict = {}
    config={
        "job_type":"Query",
        "query":{
            "query":"select number,name from my_project.my_dataset.my_table",
            "useLegacySql":False,
            "allow_large_results":True,
            "location":"location_name"
        }}
    hook = BigQueryHook(gcp_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    target_data=hook.insert_job(configuration=config, project_id=None, nowait=False)
    for row in target_data.result():
        mydict[row.number] = row.name
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='return_value', value=mydict)

def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    msg = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_mydict',key='return_value')
    print(f'printing mydict in pull_function ---> {mydict}')

with DAG('test_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, catchup=False) as dag:
    
    get_mydict = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_mydict',
        python_callable=get_bq_data,
        provide_context=True
    )
    
    pull_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pull_task', 
    python_callable=pull_function,
    provide_context=True
    )
     
    get_mydict >> pull_task
```

Answer (score 1):

mydict is created during runtime, but you are using it in the dag parsing mode (the dict is not create yet, only when the dag runs).

in order to iterate it , you need to create a task that pull the return_vlue of "get_mydict" task and then you can iterate it

also, seems like you need to use [DynamicTaskMapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html) cause you create Bash tasks according to items that creates on the fly